# programmatically access the battery settings in wp7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

So I found an app on the marketplace that acts as a shortcut for the bluetooth, WiFi and Network settings, you can create a tile for each or use one for all...

one tap and you access this certain setting.

I want to make one but I cannot seem to figure out how, I found some homebrew stuff, but I want to do it professionally, andy idea?

Comment: Hi Sherif, could you be specific about things that you have tried, and where your code seems to be failing? Your question may not get answered in it's current form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps you refer to are just wrapping calls to [ConnectionSettingsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

There is no equivalent functionality for batteries exposed by the SDK.